# What are the replacements for the order events onBeforeAddToCart and onBeforeGatewayRequestSend in Commerce 2

Tags: events, migration, plugin-craftcommerce2

I'm looking for replacements for the events `onBeforeAddToCart` and `onBeforeGatewayRequestSend`.

I used `onBeforeAddToCart` to prevent the user from adding an article from different article groups to the cart.

`onBeforeGatewayRequestSend` is used to check a mandatory field and to increment our own order/invoice numbers (the md5-style numbers are not convenient for German business).

I need to set `$event->performAction = false` and `$transaction->message = "Please agree with our terms and conditions"` if the mandatory field is not checked, like I did in Commerce 1.

Comment: I need to do the same - did you get an answer ?